# Centre bootstrap divs in the middle of an image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys so i have a background image with 5 small divs in it. I was wondering what is the best way to center the 5 divs in the middle of the image. I for some reason cant find a way to put it in the middle without using margin-left: 300px or something like this. I tried to use div align in the row but that doesn't work is well

HTML:

```
  <div class="parallax2">
     <div class="info1">
        <span class="border"></span>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2" >
              <!-- work_process -->
              <div class="work_process">
                 <div class="work_process-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                    <h4>IDEA</h4>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <!-- work_process -->
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
              <!-- work_process -->
              <div class="work_process">
                 <div class="work_process-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-bank"></i>
                    <h4>DESIGN</h4>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <!-- work_process -->
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
              <!-- work_process -->
              <div class="work_process">
                 <div class="work_process-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
                    <h4>DEVELOP</h4>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <!-- work_process -->
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
              <!-- work_process -->
              <div class="work_process">
                 <div class="work_process-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
                    <h4>TEST</h4>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <!-- work_process -->
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
              <!-- work_process -->
              <div class="work_process">
                 <div class="work_process-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                    <h4 id="three" >LAUNCH</h4>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <!-- work_process -->
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.parallax2 {
    background-image: url(https://wallpapercave.com/wp/e7KiEL3.jpg);
    min-height: 400px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.work_process {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.work_process .work_process-box {
    outline: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 2em auto 3em;
    padding: 16px 10px;
    width: 120px;
}
.work_process-box i {
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.work_process-box h4 {
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
}
```

I tried to add `Margin-left: 200px` in the work process class but i wasent sure if this is the correct way to do it. 
Any help would be great

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37120/)

Comment: use bootstrap classes for full width:
col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 instead of your current classes:
https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/DTcHh/37124/

Comment: do you want them to be one below the other.. and then centered?  like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37125/

Comment: Thanks guys but the answer is below, flex it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RonTheOld, you can turn your row into a flexbox by giving it the `diplay:flex;` property and 'justify-content: center' property to center the items in the flexbox.

I've done this as an inline style attribute on the row element for your code.

Here's a [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/qC8Flezv6v) with the code in action.

Comment: Fantastic, i really need to start using flex, everyone keeps telling me about how good it is :)

Comment: Yep, bite the bullet... it's worth it. You might have already came across this article, but in case you haven't, here's css-tricks article on [flexbox ](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)